Draw a outline mask based on image shape - Using Canny edge - updated
I would like to draw an outline mask (shape) based on the image shape.
I am using opencv-python version 4.9.0.80.
So when we have an images like these.


We want output like this without images inside. Avoid gray background(It is added so that, the outline mask based on the image shape can be visible correctly).


I have tried cv.convexHull() but the result is not coming good as expected.


I am trying this code.
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

path = '/opt/boundary-remover/SW_test2-01.png'
# path = '/opt/boundary-remover/scaled_2x.png'
# Load image
src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(path))
cv.imwrite('1_original.png', src)

# Convert image to gray and blur it
src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imwrite('2_gray.png', src_gray)

# Detect edges using Canny
canny_output = cv.Canny(src_gray, 100, 200)
cv.imwrite('3_canny.png', canny_output)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Combine all contours into a single contour
all_contours = np.concatenate(contours)

# Find the convex hull object for the combined contour
hull = cv.convexHull(all_contours)

# Draw the combined contour and its convex hull
drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green color
# cv.drawContours(drawing, [all_contours], 0, color)
# cv.imwrite('4_all_contours.png', drawing)
cv.drawContours(drawing, [hull], 0, color)
cv.imwrite('5_hull.png', drawing)

cv.drawContours(drawing, [hull], -1, color, thickness=cv.FILLED)
cv.imwrite('7_filled.png', drawing)


get all pixels that are non-gray, you will get the masks you are asking for

actually what's your starting point and what is your desired? Remove gray from the images and ge the pixels of the logo?

If I understood correctly, you want to remove the symbols from the white background? The gray background image is an example of what you would like? I can help with the masking part. You can try image dilation. You can plot the image after various steps to get an intuitive idea of what is going on. Basically, I have binarized the image and removed small salt and pepper noise with morphological opening. Then, the image is dilated with a circular kernel. This dilation 'smears' the image into the pattern you desire. Then, I fill in the gaps in dilated image. This may not be a general solution for you, but it does work for the 2 cases provided.
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def get_circular_kernel(diameter):
    """
    Author: F.Wessels
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/70886011/15279460
    """
    mid = (diameter - 1) / 2
    distances = np.indices((diameter, diameter)) - np.array([mid, mid])[:,    None, None]
    kernel = ((np.linalg.norm(distances, axis=0) - mid) <= 0).astype(int)
    return kernel


src = cv.imread(path)

cv.imshow('Original', src)

# Convert image to gray and then binarize
src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, im_th = cv.threshold(src_gray, 240, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

# remove small objects to 'clean' image
src_gray_c = cv.morphologyEx(~im_th, cv.MORPH_OPEN, (3,3))

# dilate image with a circular kernel
dilated_image = cv.dilate(src_gray_c, kernel=get_circular_kernel(20).astype(np.uint8), iterations=1)

# Author: Abid Rahman K
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317883/15279460
des = dilated_image.copy()
contour,hier = cv.findContours(des,cv.RETR_CCOMP,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contour:
    cv.drawContours(des,[cnt],0,255,-1)
final = des.copy()

cv.imshow('Final', final)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

Image 1




Image 2




Thanks for the answer. I had tried this type of approach, but in a different way. The problem with this is that we are passing 20 as a diameter in get_circular_kernel(20).
Basically, we are filling gaps. It is working here, but it will not work if we pass the same image with high dimensions (2x height and width).
Even if we are able to count the diameter value dynamically based on the image shape, it will not work if we have the image in a Circle shape(O), as the gap will be too big.

Here is an outline of an approach in Python/OpenCV. Unfortunately, my OpenCV is not working at the moment so I did the processing in Imagemagick.
read image
convert to gray
threshold on white to make a mask and invert so white is black and the rest is white
get the convex hull of the mask
get the contour of the convex hull
draw a white filled contour on a copy of the input (or a black background) for the convex hull
dilate the previous result (filled convex hull) about 10-20 pixels with a circular kernel. This will round the corners.
Put the dilated image into the alpha channel of the input


Imagemagick code:
Convert white to transparent and extract the alpha channel as a mask
Get the convex hull about the alpha channel and draw it filled with white over the input image.
Apply a circular morphology dilate kernel with size of 10 to the filled convex hull image
Add the result as the alpha channel to the image


magick image1.jpg -fuzz 15% -transparent white -alpha extract x.png
magick x.png -set option:hull "%[convex-hull]" -fill white -draw "polygon %[hull]" x2.png
magick x2.png -morphology dilate disk:10 x3.png
magick image1.jpg x3.png -compose copy_opacity -composite x4.png

Threshold image as mask

Filled convex hull

Morphology dilated convex hull

Result - dilated filled convex hull put into alpha channel of input

ADDITION
Here are the results for the second image.
Threshold image as mask

Filled convex hull

Morphology dilated convex hull

Result - dilated filled convex hull put into alpha channel of input

Download to see that it has transparent background
ADDITION 2
If you remove the convex hull step, you will get a white border that follows the shape of the letters better.

Threshold
Dilate threshold
Put dilated threshold image into alpha channel of input


For Image1 -- Imagemagick Code
magick image1.jpg -fuzz 15% -transparent white -alpha extract z.png
magick z.png -morphology dilate disk:10 z2.png
magick image1.jpg z2.png -compose copy_opacity -composite z3.png

Threshold:

Dilate:

Result1:


For Image2:
Threshold:

Dilate:

Result2:


The problem with the convex hull is that it doesn’t have circular edges, and it will not work for the text image (check out the 2nd Betset text image; it's the final result I have shared).

You overlook the fact that the dilation of 10-20 pixels with a circular kernel will round the corners.  I have corrected my images to properly show that.

@ NiRmaL See my comment above and my changes in my answer above.

Thanks for more clarity, but in the expected output, we need a mask based on the image shape. For example, if padding of 10px applies, it should be 10px from all outside edges. Please check the image with the text "Betset" in the expected output I have shared. The convex hull is giving frame-like output, so in "Betset", we are getting more gaps near B_t__t (e_se form Betset).

@NiRmaL Look at my answer and that example and the code. I processed the image to threshold to get the mask and put that into the alpha channel of the image. You have to choose the correct threshold. Try using cv2.inRange if using OpenCV with an upper range of pure white and lower range about 15% below that. If you still get something else, show your code and threshold result.

@NiRmaL Sorry, I now understand your issue.  I will have to look further into that.

@NiRmaL OK, I just removed the convex hull step and now the outline white follows the shape of the letters better.  See ADDITION 2 in my answer.

Thanks for taking an interest in this. Sorry for the late reply. If you check the Dilate image for the diamond shape (above Result1). We are seeing a gap in the center of the image. For the expected result, we don't need that. We want to consider only outside borders. Not inside. If we have a ring shape image(0) this approach will not work. We would like to support parallel objects as well(||).

Increase the dilate until it fills the center. The erode if needed to get down to the thickness you want for the outline.

If I understood your question correctly based on what you said here: Avoid gray background, then here is one way:
def replaceGrayWithWhite(im):
    imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mask = (imGray>250).astype(np.uint8)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    maskFilled = cv2.drawContours(mask.copy(), contours, -1, 1, -1)
    maskFilledInv = cv2.bitwise_not(maskFilled) - 254
    '''
    Took this from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38493075/16815358
    '''
    foreground = cv2.bitwise_or(im, im, mask=maskFilled)
    background = 255*np.ones_like(im)
    background = cv2.bitwise_and(background, background, mask=maskFilledInv)
    final = cv2.bitwise_or(foreground, background)
    return final

imports are numpy and opencv, here are the results:



No, the gray background I have added is so that the outline mask based on the image shape can be visible correctly. I have updated the description.

so you want to go from white background image to gray background image?

If so greenerpasture's answer should be good for what you want

Thanks. There are a few issues with the approach of the greenerpasture's answer. I have added a comment for that.
